# Project Euler #75: ways to optimize the algorithm

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

I'm looking at ways to optimize my algorithm for solving [Project Euler #75](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=75), two things I have done so far are,

1. Only check L with even values as this can be easily proved.
2. Store L values that have been verified to have only one way to form an integer sided right angle triangle. Later on, when checking a new L value, I look for L's divisors that are already verified to have this quality. If there are 2 or more divisors, then this value is skipped. E.g. 12, 30 and 40 are stored (24, 36, etc. are not stored because they are really enlarged versions of 12), so when I see 60 or 120, I can quickly determine that they should be skipped.

However my algorithm is still not quick enough. Do you have other suggestions or links to relevant articles? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple

and

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formulas_for_generating_Pythagorean_triples

EDIT

I just solved the problem, using one of this formulas, If you need extra hint just post comment

Comment: I abandoned my original approach and used Euclid's formula to generate Pythagorean triples and my program finished in a couple of seconds with correct result. Thanks.